# Scala getting java exception while trying to create RDD which has more than 255 columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge data set with almost 600 columns but, while I am trying to create a DF it is failing with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Too many arguments in method signature in class file
```

Sample code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val data = sc.textFile(file);
  val rd = data.map(line => line.split(",")).map(row => new Parent(row(0), row(1), ........row(600)))
  rd.toDF.write.mode("append").format("orc").insertInto("Table")
}
```

Can someone help how to perform workaround for this?.

Comment: Did you try reading the data directly as a DF with `spark.read.csv()`?

Comment: Java does not support methods with more than 55 for static and 254 for non-static methods. You can change your `Parent` to have a `List[String]` as the single member.

Comment: I dont think I can use CSV here, some other cases I might go with different delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a limit on maximum method arguments for a Java object, which therefore extends to Scala object as well. A Person class with 600 params would be unfeasible.

The most ideal solution would be to read the csv natively as:

```
spark.read.csv(filePath)
```

Additionally, you may choose to increase the maxColumns option, using the signature.

```
spark.read.options().csv()
```

While it does not directly affect your use-case, the max-columns is set to 20480. More information on these parameters can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(scala.collection.Seq)).

Comment: What if my delimiter is not comma instead of that i have some delimiter like "~"

Comment: You can use the "sep" to change the separator to whichever character you desire while using spark CSV. Look at the java/scaladoc linked in the answer for more information on the sep option.